# String Split not working

Tags: javascript, max-msp-jitter

I'm having a problem with splitting strings in Javascript in Max/MSP.

outlet is the Max/MSP version of printf etc.

The string splits weirdly, but it seems to only output both words comma seperated.

```
function sample_callback(args)  // Callback
{
    var keyword=args;
    var trackname=keyword.toString().split(" ");
    var name = trackname[0]; // trackname[1] outputs nothing.
    outlet(0, name);
}
```

Any help is greatly received.

Comment: I suspect that the code calling the callback, sample_callback, isn't binding correctly, but no way to tell w/o that call.  Can you include some of the code that calls sample_callback?

Comment: Please show us how you're calling `sample_callback`, and the definition of `outlet`. BTW: if you're coming from a C/C++ background, bear in mind that JS has more in common with Scheme/Lisp, so treat functions as objects (pass them as arguments/return values at will)

Comment: I've realised a mistake but it still doesn't work - I've edited the question. Thanks for you're quick reply so far.

Comment: What is the value returned from `keyword.toString()`?

Comment: It returned the words comma separated instead of space. It must have converted it during the toString function. Thank you @Aaron Kurtzhals

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Big thanks to Aaron Kurtzhals . Hopefully the upvote in the comment counts towards your rep!

A simple overlooked checking of what the string is helped me out. oops. The working code is now..

```
function sample_callback(args)  // Callback
{
  var keyword=args.toString();
  var trackname=keyword.split(",");
  var name = trackname[0];
  outlet(0, name);
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
function sample_callback(args)  // Callback
{
    var keyword=args.toString()`enter code here`;
    var trackname=keyword.toString().split(" ");
    var name = trackname[0]; // trackname[1] outputs nothing.
    outlet(0, name);
}
```